# How to select a single date in date picker php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli

How can I pick a single date from my date range picker?

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
       });  
       $(function(){  
            $("#from_date").datepicker();  
            $("#to_date").datepicker();  
       });  
       $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
            var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
            if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      url:"filtertable.php",  
                      method:"POST",  
                      data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                      success:function(data)  
                      {  
                           $('#order_table').html(data);  
                      }  
                 });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 </script>
```

here's my query coming from the date range picker:

```
  query = "SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND 
'".$_POST["to_date"]."'
```

If u I try to select 2 same dates it doesn't work because of this

```
 $query = "SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND 
'".$_POST["to_date"]."' ";
```

I need to add a statement which is

```
`$query ="SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime = '".$_POST["from_date"]."' OR 
'".$_POST["to_date"]."' ";
```

how can I add this condition to the old query?

Comment: @apokryfos i'm so sorry I will edit that tags now.

Comment: My point wasn't to add the tag. My point was to review the question itself to emphasize more on where the problem is and not where the problem isn't . I'm assuming the JavaScript is working so there's no reason to provide the entire detail of it just add the `$.ajax` part and mention what the content of `from_date` and `to_date` is. Someone who just wanders in here and looks at the wall of code will most likely hit the back button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of between you can just do the manual:

```
SELECT *
FROM gsm2 
WHERE setTime >= :fromTime AND setTime <= :toTime
```

Notice how I'm using placeholders there? You should too, and also use prepared statements.

In practice if you are using MySQLi you could do:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(...); //Your connection
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime >= ? AND setTime <= ?");

$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "from_date");
$to = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "to_date");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $from, $to);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
// Do things like $res->fetch_assoc or similar here
```

Note that if your $_POST data are dates but your SQL fields are `DATETIME` then you might need to do some sort of casting e.g. do `WHERE DATE(setTime) >= ? AND DATE(setTime) <= ?`

Comment: Sorry I am new to sql, I tried using your code and it says `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: @Theodore you need to bind the parameters :fromTime and :toTime to your actual variables to make the query work. Search for prepared statements to learn how

Comment: @LelioFaieta just like this? `<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>`?

Comment: @Theodore check the update for MySQLi specifically. Although I find PDO easier to work with if you're just starting out learning

Comment: @LelioFaieta I will work this one out and tell you the result later. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong (as I'm not equipped to test it right now), but this should work:

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN ".$_POST['from_date']." AND ".$_POST['to_date'].";
```

Going by the assumption that your initial query was right, but your PHP code was throwing up some errors as you are using loads of (' and ")'s.

Mainly posting to point out that you are accepting user input and throwing it straight into a SQL query. I am honestly surprised that in 2018 on StackOverflow, so many users in this category are placing PHP input variables directly into a SQL query and then executing it without checking the input to ensure that it is valid first.

Input such as `1; DROP TABLE gsm2;` could have the potential to delete your entire table. I'm not sure what kind of server-side firewalls are in place to deal with this type of attack, but it's terrible practice all the same.

Comment: I am so sorry about my bad coding, I am very new to sql and I will promise to learn the necessary precautions to avoid sql injection.

Comment: It's no problem, but you do need to be careful because malicious users will take advantage. And yeah, I wasn't sure if my above query would work, I'm not in a position for testing right now and just noticed that there were issues with your initial query so maybe this would work if i cleaned it up. The query I posted above looks fine to me, but if your date being entered is not an integer or the values within the database for setTime are not integers, I don't think that query will work (unless maybe if there was an ORDER specified).